# Sorting a string with words and numbers at alternate position in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, selection-sort

Ex- If my string is- "Friend 32 Hello 12"
My output should be- "hello 12 friend 32"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[100][100],temp[100];
    int i,j,c;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++) 
    {
    scanf("%s",a[i]);
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            if(isupper(a[i][j]))
           a[i][j]=a[i][j]+32;
        }
    }
    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<99;i=i+2)
    {
        for(j=i+2;j<100;j=j+2)
        {
           c=strcmp(a[i],a[j]);
           if(c>0)
           {
           *temp=*a[i];
           *a[i]=*a[j];
           *a[j]=*temp;

         }
        }

    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i=i+2) 
    {
        printf("%s",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand where my code is wrong. It's printing some garbage values.
I am using selection sort algorithm.

Comment: temp=*a[i]; is it valid ?

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally posted the old code. It should be *temp=*a[i]

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you expect anyone to read it.

Comment: The sorting rule isn't quite clear. Do you sort two independent, but interleaved arrays of strings and numbers? Or do you sort pairs of strings and numbers by the number, keeping original string/number pairs?

Comment: The latter. I am trying to sort the strings in one pass and the numbers in the other.

Comment: for(i=0;i<100;i++) 
    {
    scanf("%s",a[i]);
    } what you will enter 100 times ?

Comment: I am compiling it in gcc. So after every space the word gets stored in a separate string. i.e Hello at a[0]

Comment: So you really mean the former: The strings are sorted and the numers are sorted and the result is an alternating sequence of strings and numbers, where strings and following numbers do not stay together during sorting.

Comment: Your swapping mechanism just swaps the first letter of the strings but keeps the rest in place.

Comment: No definitely the latter. I am swapping them in pairs. The string gets swapped with string in the first pass. And in the next pass the number get swapped with  a number.

Comment: And no it couldn't possibly just swap the first digit as we are dealing with a 2d array here. a[i] would return the address of the string at ith position. Or maybe I am wrong

Comment: Could you help me out with the correct code to do what I want to?

Comment: Well, just swapping the first letter is what your code does. That's also the output of the program. (I don't see garbage letters, by the way, only all words pasted together. You might want to print a new-line after each word.) If you must keep the pairs, you must swap the pairs simultaneously.

Comment: How do I do that? I am pretty confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88073/discussion-between-aakanksha-pandey-and-m-oehm).

Comment: Step: Use any sorting algoritham for sort your input string the nin that algoritham use to condition one for number and another for string and follow for yr input string may be its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort 50 pairs of strings and numbers according to the number. To do so, you have defined an array of 100 strings. I suggest that you represent the data as two arrays of 50 integers and 50 strings. (That's just a first idea, see below for a better recommendation.)

Strings in C are really arrays of characters that have a null byte at the end. You cannot assign arrays to each other, but you can copy their contents. If you want to swap the strings, you have to copy the actual chars. The function `strcpy` from `<string.h>` dies this for you.

When you sort the arrays, you do the comparison just on one array, but swap both arrays simultaneously. The number swap is straightforawrd, the string swap requires deep copys with `strcpy`.

Here's a first draft:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 50
#define MAXLEN 40

int main(void)
{
    char str[N][MAXLEN];
    int num[N];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%s%d", str[i], &num[i]) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input format!");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (j = 0; str[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            str[i][j] = tolower(str[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", str[i], num[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (num[i] > num[j]) {
                int tnum;
                char tstr[MAXLEN];

                tnum = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j]; 
                num[j] = tnum;

                strcpy(tstr, str[i]);
                strcpy(str[i], str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], tstr);
            }
        }
    }

    puts("--");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", str[i], num[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The usual approach when you have to keep things together is to pack them into a struct.  You can then move entire structs around without worrying that the string and number go out of sync.

Structs can be assigned to each other; their content is then copied. That makes for easier swapping. Another advantage is that structs lend themselves to be sorted with the standard sorting routine `qsort` from `<stdlib.h>`.

So let's do that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 50
#define MAXLEN 40

struct pair_t {
    char str[MAXLEN];
    int num;    
};

int main(void)
{
    struct pair_t pair[N]; 
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%s%d", pair[i].str, &pair[i].num) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input format!");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (j = 0; pair[i].str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            pair[i].str[j] = tolower(pair[i].str[j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", pair[i].str, pair[i].num);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (pair[i].num > pair[j].num) {
                struct pair_t tmp;

                tmp = pair[i];
                pair[i] = pair[j]; 
                pair[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    puts("--");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", pair[i].str, pair[i].num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Finally – but that's a more advanced topic – if your structs are long, you end up swapping a lot of bytes, which is not very efficient. You could create an array of pointers to your pair and just sort the pointers and leave the original array in place.